# onkeyup on each row occurence and calculation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am doing a table of currencies pulled from the database. So each currency will create an occurence in a while loop and user has to enter their value and calculates them onkeyup. The problem is, the function i created to calculate each td based on currency doens work very well. the conversion rate only apply to the last TD

here's my code,

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MASUKKAN SETORAN UNTUK = <b><?php echo $sr; ?></b> ~ <?php echo $flightnum; ?></h4>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="paymentTable">
                <thead>
                    <th>NO</th>
                    <th>MATA UANG</th>
                    <th>RATE</th>
                    <th>SETORAN</th>
                    <th>TOTAL IDR</th>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $i = 1;
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$row[curr_id]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[curr_code] - $row[curr_desc]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[conv_rate]</td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='number' onkeyup='processCurr($i);' id='inputCurr$i'/></td>";
                            echo "<td><label id='calculatedCurr$i'></label></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript function,

```
<script>
    function processCurr(param){
        var inputcurr= $('#inputCurr'+param).val();
        $('#paymentTable tr').each(function() {
            var convRate = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
            $('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * convRate);

        });
    }
</script>
```

so the convRate are same in each TD which i dont want. each row should have their own convRate pulled from the database and call its function to calculate the total in IDR with onkeyup.

Please help me,..

here i attached the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you add the rendered `html`?

Comment: take a look at the screenshot

Comment: @Konz Mama screenshot does not provide the `html` structure. It is always good to make the questions easily understandable so that everyone can help.

Comment: @RinoRaj i edited with full html...

Comment: $('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * convRate); //this code causing the problem
convRate value taken will be the last value in iteration.See my answer for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in the line

**$('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * convRate);**

Here the final value of convRate will be the last table row value that gets multiplied with inputcurr to give the result.On each iteration, $('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * convRate) value getting overwritten.

I assume what you  want is to output as Total IDR=RATE * SETORAN.Your code can be optimized to get the answer.You should also assign some unique id value to get your convRate .The optimized solution is given below.

PHP code

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$row[curr_id]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[curr_code] - $row[curr_desc]</td>";
                            echo "<td><span id='convRate".$i."'>$row[conv_rate]</span></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='number' onkeyup='processCurr(".$i.");' id='inputCurr".$i."'/></td>";
                            echo "<td><label id='calculatedCurr".$i."'></label></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i++;
                    }
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
    function processCurr(param){
        var inputcurr= $('#inputCurr'+param).val();
        var convRate=$('#convRate'+param).val();
        $('#calculatedCurr'+param).html(inputcurr * convRate);   

    }
</script>
```